# DJI Mobile SDK - Error when calling sendVirtualStickFlightControlData

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm programming an app for a DJI Mavic Pro and when trying to control it with the following code:

```
flightController = ((Aircraft) DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct()).getFlightController();

...

case "turn_right":
      new FlightControlData(0,0,90,0);
      break;
case "turn_left":
      new FlightControlData(0,0,-90,0);
      break;

...

if(flightController!=null)
                if(flightController.isVirtualStickControlModeAvailable())
                    flightController.sendVirtualStickFlightControlData(Data, djiError -> {
                        if(djiError!=null)
                            showToast((djiError.toString()));
                    });
```

I would expect this to work, but for some reason I get the following error message and error code 255:

```
The key does not match the format: component/index/key with index being a number or *.
```

I searched around but can't really understand what this means, it must be related to the SDK Keys since the error is called INVALID_KEY_FORMAT, but I don't have any knowledge on what a key is and what could be wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I fixed the issue, I'm very dumb and forgot to attribute the new created object to the Flight Control Data variable I was trying to pass

```
case "turn_right":
      Data=new FlightControlData(0,0,90,0);
      break;
case "turn_left":
      Data=new FlightControlData(0,0,-90,0);
      break;
```

fixes the issue, however the given error is kinda bad, should be more clear since it was literally a null input being passed

Comment: You don't schedule your flightControlData for repetitive sending? In DJI demo app they schedule flight control data to send in an interval of 200ms, to perform a frequency of 5Hz, conform to the limits of 5 - 25Hz (https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html#djiflightcontroller_virtualstickcontrolmodecategory_sendvirtualstickflightcontroldata_inline).
What happens in your way to send? Rapid movement and stop?